# Умно или умнО?  крАсно или краснО?

Tags: ударение

Как правильно и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

умнО, нареч.!неправ. Умно. умнО придумано.

Умный,прил. кр. ф. умнО, удар. Умно, Умны устар. Орфоэпический словарь русского языка И. Л. Резниченко   Напр. умнО решение.

КрАсно,в знач. сказ. (о цвете). Кругом крАсно от пожара.

КраснО, нареч. Разг. Красноречиво, складно. Говорит краснО. словарь трудностей Розенталь Теленкова .